# set the value of child element to a parameter of parent element dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my following code:

```
   <div class="w3-container" id="menuTopics">
          <button>
            <a href="//somesite.com/someparam"> 
                <img src="/images/keywordicons/leadership.svg" class="keyicon" />Leadership
            </a>
       </button>
       <button>.......</button>
 </div>
```

I want to set an onclick event for the button like this which will hold the value of the href attribute

```
   <div class="w3-container" id="menuTopics">
          <button onclick="window.location.href='//somesite.com/someparam'">
            <a href="//somesite.com/someparam"> 
                <img src="/images/keywordicons/leadership.svg" class="keyicon" />Leadership
            </a>
       </button>
       <button>.......</button>
 </div>
```

since href holds the value of the url, I want the same for onclick event. This is my requirement.

The following is the javascript I have written.

```
   var getChilds = document.querySelectorAll("#menuTopics button");
        getChilds.forEach(function (item) {
            item.setAttribute('onclick', 'location.href=""');

        })
```

However I donot know how to get the value of the href from **a** tag.

Comment: Simply remove the <button> element, the <a> element does everything you need.

Comment: `<button><a href>..</a></button>` is not valid anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the href value to assign it.

```js
var getChilds = document.querySelectorAll("#menuTopics button");
var href = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
getChilds.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute('onclick', `location.href='${href}'`);
})


var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

console.log('these are your buttons with on click events', ...buttons)
```

```html
<div class="w3-container" id="menuTopics">
  <button>
            <a href="//somesite.com/someparam"> 
                <img src="/images/keywordicons/leadership.svg" class="keyicon" />Leadership
            </a>
       </button>
  <button>.......</button>
</div>
```